# Sizing I-beams for two Floors to replace LVLs

Tags: floor, beam, column

I had an engineer size some LVLs to help support an existing(sagging) floor.
See image for majority of info needed. 
The Blue beam is (3) 14" LVLs laminated [192" (16' 0") Long] and the Red beam is (4) 14" LVLs laminated [234" (19' 6") Long]. The Blue beam is supporting the uniform load of 15,200 lbs. The Red beam is supporting half of that as a center point load. (7600 lbs)
I am searching for what size I-Beam (W-beam) would be required to substitute for the LVLs.
The beams are supported where the Green squares are. 
Looking for at least L/360 deflection or better if possible. Headspace is the issue so would prefer beam height to be smaller.
[image]

Comment: Have you considered going back to the engineer who did this analysis and getting some alternative material recommendations?  BTW, going from LVL to steel beams is going to be a significant increase in price, but I'm sure you know that already.

Comment: Struct engineer here. Just pay your engineer to give you the alternate

Comment: Engineer that sized the LVLs works for LVL company. Says they dont size Steel. I'm just looking to see if anyone here had the knowledge to size an equivalent Steel beam or steel beams to handle stated loads as a second opinion.

Comment: This is more of a engineering question and really off topic for a DIY in my opinion. *note without an engendered stamp can you get a permit OR insurance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op asked for engineering requirements that reflect safety standards .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

1. I am not a licensed architect or engineer.   I do however produce plans that I get a stamp on or have the local inspector agree to.
2. I usually would not give someone advice on load beams that are not uniform - you are spanning two different load configurations here and doing a bit of stacking.
3. Since you already have LVLs and the description of your issue I am assuming that the load calculations are right, footers are suitable and working, and the support beams are sufficient.

I use https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ for a lot of information - I actually found the site from an architect that I use.   The chart below is from their site.   I ALWAYS add an extra 25% of allowance to anything I size myself.  You should be using this as a reference and work with someone that can look at the full layout of your building.

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that the same size W8x28 Beam would be used for both beams? Just clarifying since you didnt specify for Red/Blue or both.

Comment: @Gremlin - no sorry that was just highlighted when I got the photo.   Obviously that won't work for the 20' span you have.   Honestly I would probably get that for the 14' and W10x30 for the 20'.   But I oversize everything out of habit.   An engineer might tell you W8x18 and W10x22... that might save you a little money.

Comment: I think the OP is confused about the loading, it's not 15,300 plf but 15300 total, which is 950 plf and in the reasonable range. But I now question if there is also a mistake about it being uniform, it might be a point load. In anyway case, deflection is going to control the 19.5 beam, not strength. I understand that there are more than one load and sizing calculators online. But whatever you're doing, I know it needs a permit. Please get one. The codes are there in large part to protect us, and others, from harming ourselves or other. They are not there to get us or make $

Comment: @Ack - I agree and I didn't want to get into a debate with OP but how could the load be uniform if the beams were stacked?   I mean if this were true then the 20' span could be replaced by a metal column.   I gave him information so he can have a more intelligent conversation with an engineer.   This obviously isn't on par with making a room opening bigger.   And he is currently having issues... which he should be asking engineer to explain why the current LVLs are having issues and does he just need a bigger beam - or is there some other issue going on too?

Comment: @DMoore - Your answer and comments here imply that you think that the OP already has the LVL beams installed, By my read of the question the OP is looking to fix a sagging floor and went to the engineer to get sizing for the LVL beams. Upon realizing that the 14" height of the LVL beams would be a huge detriment to head clearance I believe the OP is looking for some other option to consider that would have less than 14" height.  Another thing I do not understand why the blue beam needs to be stacked on top of the red one. Couldn't the blue beam just butt to the red beam in some type of hanger?

Comment: @MichaelKaras - you are right there - I read that a bit wrong.   I am guessing there are actually two different joist patterns and the blue beam is deflecting some of the load onto some point footings that the red beam has.   It makes sense to me.   As for connecting the ibeams you can get them fabricated where blue sits in red and clamped/bolted.   This will cost a lot compared to a basic ibeam clamp with one siting on top.   I have not seen a side hanger used on ibeams.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - Also whatever is going on we are asked to solve AxB=C and we only know A.   And I doubt A (load on blue) is right.   We don't know the load on the red beam and we don't know the deferment of the load from blue.   Also it isn't clear where the leveling issues are most persistent... so is the floor out of whack on red or blue more?   I cannot see it being uniform.    And then can the footer and columns handle this - is he solving one issue and causing another (footer sinking).

Comment: @DMoore, "side hangers" as you incorrectly call them are one of the most common connections for steel!  Search single shear bolted beam connection. This question is a set up for, and the answers are well down the path of [Dangerous answers]( https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/dangerous-answers?rq=1). The OP needs to seek out a local engineer to look at his specific situation

Comment: @Ack - that's why I didn't give him an answer.  Also I was just referring to Michael's comment, not calling anything anything.   I am not sure what you call things but these have always been referred by my engineers as collars or clamps.   If you call them hangers I am learning something new every day!

Comment: The load on Blue is correct. 15,200 Uniform or 950 Plf, whichever you prefer. It is uniform because there is already a floor there. 2x10's on 12" Centers runnning Perpendicular to Blue. There are no other loads on Red. Just supporting Blue to prevent introducing a Column. I could add alot more information but was concerned it would cause too many other questions and be too long..   Sounds like it created questions anyway.  The steel beams would not be stacked like the LVLs are currently shown. They would be butted together like a T.